# python is only printing first letter of word

Tags: python, python-2.7

section[0] is only printing the first letter, R, of RESIDENT.  I am stumped!  Why isn't it printing the whole word?

you can see the format of the php file by clicking on the link
http://www.capitalsurface.com/addresses.php

```
import urllib
from time import sleep

while True:
link = "http://www.capitalsurface.com/addresses.php"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
content = f.read()

if content:
    array = content.split("\n")

    for line in array:

        print ""

        address = line.split(":")
        for section in address:
            print section[0]            
else:
    print "NO DATA"

sleep(15)
```

Comment: try printing address

Comment: Each `section` is a colon-separated piece of `address`. So each `section[0]` is the first character of a colon-separated piece of `address`. If you want the whole thing instead of the first character, just don't do the `[0]`.

Comment: Please fix the code indentation. It is not clear what your code is doing.

Comment: I'm sorry about the formatting, my browser doesn't work well on this webpage.  I need to get each section of the address in a variable.  I'm a little confused.  I'm new to Python, sorry. I was assuming section[0] would = RESIDENT, section[1] would be the first part of the address and section[2] the last part of the address and then I could process that data before moving to the next address

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
address = line.split(":")
for section in address:
    print section[0]
```

You haven't shown us any sample input, but presumably address is something like this:

```
'RESIDENT:1234 ANY DR:SPRINGFIELD:MG:12345:USA'
```

So, `address` will be:

```
['RESIDENT', '1234 ANY DR', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'MG', '12345', 'USA']
```

And then each `section` will be an element of that list, like:

```
'RESIDENT'
```

So `section[0]` will be the first letter of that element, like:

```
'R'
```

And that's exactly what you're seeing.

If you want to see `RESIDENT`, just print out `section` instead of `section[0]`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks... my input actually is showing an extra line for some reason.  So it was making address[1] go out of range... then I kept changing things trying to figure it why.  I appreciate the explanation